# fgetcsv not returning all the columns

Tags: php, fgetcsv

I am using the following to load a `csv` file which has about 100 columns. However is only reads the first 77. It gets the correct number of rows. No row is longer than 1000 chars. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

```
$file = $_FILES['csv1']['tmp_name']; 
$handle = fopen($file,"r"); 

$matrix = array();
while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) 
{
$matrix[] = $row;
}

$rows = count($matrix);
$cols = count($matrix[$row]);
echo "rows: ".$rows." cols: ".$cols ."<br>";
```

Comment: Show some of your csv.... the only limitation built into fgetcsv() is the bytecount (it's bytes, not characters), but if your file is malformed, or if that is a character count for dual/multibyte characters, then it may cause problems

Comment: I ran into this problem with reports that are thrown out by a rather silly system we have to use at work. Check that there are actually 100 commas on each line; if the same as my issue, it is caused by blank data being omited from the end of the line rather than having the commas delimiting the blank data. My fix was to simply zero-fill the resultant array to the correct size, not sure if that would be suitable in your case.

Comment: Could it be anything to do with creating a csv on a Mac?